# MYSQL: Use SELECT result in Subquery OR get the MIN(row number)

Tags: mysql

I have this problem, i'm trying to get the first row from subquery joinded with a 1st SELECT (the 1st row depends on result from the first SELECT) and i tried 2 things so far without any success:

**Approach 1:**

```
SELECT 
    gsm_solde.id AS id
    , gsm_solde.date AS DATES
    , gsm_solde.IdArticle AS IdArticle

    , E.DateE
    , E.QteE
FROM    gsm_solde

LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT 
                     gds_entree_detail.id_stk
                    , gds_entree_detail.qte_new AS QteE
                    , gds_entree_detail.pmp_new AS PmpE
                    , gds_entree.date AS DateE
                    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gds_entree_detail.id_stk ORDER BY gds_entree.date DESC, gds_entree_detail.id DESC) row_num
                FROM gds_entree 
                INNER JOIN gds_entree_detail ON gds_entree.id = gds_entree_detail.IdMouvement
            ) E
ON gsm_solde.IdArticle = E.id_stk AND E.DateE <= gsm_solde.Date
AND E.row_num = 1

WHERE gsm_solde.date BETWEEN 20220619000000 AND 20220619235959
GROUP BY gsm_solde.id
```

This does not work because **row_num** does not start at 1 anymore because **E.DateE <= gsm_solde.Date** is outside of the subquery.
so i'm thinking, how can i replace **E.row_num = 1** by something like **E.row_num = MIN(E.row_num)**

**Approach 2:**

```
SELECT 
    gsm_solde.id AS id
    , gsm_solde.date AS DATES
    , gsm_solde.IdArticle AS IdArticle

    , E.DateE
    , E.QteE
FROM    gsm_solde

LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT 
                     gds_entree_detail.id_stk
                    , gds_entree_detail.qte_new AS QteE
                    , gds_entree_detail.pmp_new AS PmpE
                    , gds_entree.date AS DateE
                    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gds_entree_detail.id_stk ORDER BY gds_entree.date DESC, gds_entree_detail.id DESC) row_num
                FROM gds_entree 
                INNER JOIN gds_entree_detail ON gds_entree.id = gds_entree_detail.IdMouvement
                WHERE E.DateE <= gsm_solde.Date
            ) E
ON gsm_solde.IdArticle = E.id_stk
AND E.row_num = 1

WHERE gsm_solde.date BETWEEN 20220619000000 AND 20220619235959
GROUP BY gsm_solde.id
```

This will solve i think the **ROW_NUMBER** issue but In this case **gsm_solde.Date** is UNKNOWN .

Sample Data:

**gsm_solde**

| Id | Date | IdArticle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202206190900 | 1 |
| 2 | 202206191100 | 1 |
| 3 | 202206191300 | 1 |

**gds_entree**

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 202206190800 |
| 2 | 202206191000 |
| 3 | 202206191200 |
| 4 | 202206191400 |
| 5 | 202206191600 |

**gds_entree_detail**

| Id | IdMouvement | Id_stk | qte_new | pmp_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 100 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 200 | 2000 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 300 | 3000 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 400 | 4000 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | 500 | 5000 |

**Expected results**

| gsm_solde.id | DATES | IdArticle | E.DateE | E.QteE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202206190900 | 1 | 202206191000 | 200 |
| 2 | 202206191100 | 1 | 202206191200 | 300 |
| 3 | 202206191300 | 1 | 202206191400 | 400 |

Comment: sample data and expected outcome would help

Comment: Here are some data and expected results, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Your queries doesn't seem to run with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. This option ensures that the grouping is made explicit and not 'by chance'. The second query doesn't even run.
I made a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cb99d65b1df2ddb483808e905ebfd0a9) with a minimal and simple approach using `bigint` as the datatype. Also, if the database will run in a Linux server, notice that [Mysql is case sensitive in Linux](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html), so `date` and `Date` are different.

Comment: Actually sample data didn't help an I haven't been able to reverse engineer your intention, try explaining in plain english

Comment: The query works fine on a windows server, and this is a small part of a bigger query, the data in fact is irrelevant , i'm not trying to make the query work, i'm just trying to have an answer to the two questions above.

Comment: actually, i'm trying to have the last 
gds_entree_detail.qte_new AS QteE
, gds_entree.date AS DateE
For every gsm_solde